# SMD component identification: 6-pin diode

Tags: pcb, diodes, analog, identification, components

I need some help identifying this IC and I've had no luck so far. I know it's a diode since it has a "CR" designation (and other CR's on this board are also diodes), but it's a 6-pin SMD and I don't seem to have much luck finding either PC5 or C5. Would anyone be able to help me?

[image: SMD Component]

Comment: If you know for sure it's a diode (or rather multiple diodes in a package), it's likely an ESD protection device.

Comment: There is probably not enough information in this question to id this part. There are just too many devices with this packaging. To narrow it down a bit, some information about the connections and ideally a schematic is needed. At the very least you should try to take some photos of the surrounding circuits.